# Update sqlite row with filter of double values (latitude/longitude) doesnt work

Tags: java, android, sqlite, google-maps, double

I want to update my values in SQLite database by latitude/longitude(converted doubles to strings) criteria.This update works but not always.Sometimes it doesnt update row with existing latitude/longitude.I think its some problem with comparing SQLite REAL type numbers.

```
    public static final String ACCOUNT_FILTER = "account = ?";
    public static final String LAT_LONG_FILTER = " AND latitude =? AND longitude =?";
    getActivity().getContentResolver().update(FeedContract.Entry.CONTENT_URI,
                            updateValues,
                            ACCOUNT_FILTER+ LAT_LONG_FILTER,
                            new String[] {
                                    accountName,
                                    Double.toString(marker.getPosition().latitude),
                                    Double.toString(marker.getPosition().longitude) });
```

and database structure:

```
private static final String TYPE_TEXT = " TEXT";
    private static final String TYPE_REAL = " REAL";
    private static final String TYPE_INTEGER = " INTEGER";
    private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";

    private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE "
            + FeedContract.Entry.TABLE_NAME + " (" + FeedContract.Entry._ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + FeedContract.Entry.COLUMN_NAME_POINT_ID + TYPE_INTEGER
            + COMMA_SEP + FeedContract.Entry.COLUMN_NAME_LATITUDE
            + TYPE_REAL + COMMA_SEP
            + FeedContract.Entry.COLUMN_NAME_LONGITUDE + TYPE_REAL
            + COMMA_SEP + FeedContract.Entry.COLUMN_NAME_DATE_OF_INSERT
            + TYPE_INTEGER + COMMA_SEP
            + FeedContract.Entry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + TYPE_TEXT + COMMA_SEP
            + FeedContract.Entry.COLUMN_NAME_INFO + TYPE_TEXT + COMMA_SEP
            + FeedContract.Entry.COLUMN_NAME_ACCOUNT + TYPE_TEXT + ")";
```

Comment: Do you have any real examples of values used when it fails to update?

Comment: yes,cause i am calling update by click on marker's infowindow,and that marker's data already in db(i used content provider helper android program to be sure 100%).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i used latitude/longitude values in SQLite rows as Strings(TEXT).Converting on read/write provided by methods:

```
 Double.parseDouble(yourString);
    String.valueOf(yourDouble);
```